# Is it not longer possible to script user and permissions using SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I tried right clicking on a database, going to tasks, generate scripts, and then selecting a few users I wanted to script and in the advanced options I was sure to include the option to script permissions.

However, after doing this I am only getting the create user statement, but none of their permissions.

This appears to have changed in the last year or two?

EDIT:
If I go to generate scripts, select specific database objects, Users, select 5 users.  Pick Advanced and then Script Object-Level Permissions = True.

It scrips out my users but not detailed permissions.

If they are a member of a role, it alters the role to add them as a member, but if they have explicit DELETE or SELECT on a table, it does not include that scripted permission.

Am I just going crazy, I could have sworn it used to do that?

Comment: Did you include the objects in said script?

Comment: Yes, good point.   I selected the 5 users I wanted in the selection.
Choose objects, selected specific database objects, Users, clicked the 5 I wanted .

Then Advanced and selected "Script Object-Level Permissions" as True.